# how to get the area of a polygon in python API?

Tags: python, mesh

I would need to get and compare the area of the polygons/faces of objects of different shape. I found the variable 'area' in class bpy.types.MeshPolygon but this does not give me the real area of the polygon after scaling and modifying a mesh primitive. Why is this? Is there another way to get the area?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you scale the mesh geometry in edit mode, or is the object datablock scaled?  Perhaps if you use <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> to apply the scale it will adjust the mesh so that the area is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I had indeed overlooked applying the scaling!

Comment: The short answer is with `my_face.calc_area()`, but anyone trying to calculate polygon area should check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/151217/2952), because quads may return incorrect area values unless first triangulated.